# Как убрать стандартную верхнюю панель с названием проекта?

Tags: android

[image]

Comment: Купить приложение :)

Вопрос вообще непонятен, вы программируете под андройд или что?

Comment: Как много желающих помочь девушке :)

Comment: Наверно и мне стоит зарегатся под ником ТАНЯ =)

Comment: @Gorets придется еще научиться задавать вопросы скриншотами :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
 <activity
    android:name=".MyActivity"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" />
```

добавить в манифесте

Answer (score 6):

в onCreate нужной активити перед

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); // << это есть
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE); // << это вставить именно сюда
setContentView(R.layout.about_screen);// << это есть
```

Comment: спасибо :)проблема решена.

Comment: Принципиальный пунктик в этом - порядок строк должен быть именно таким. Между ними могут быть другие строки, но порядок не менять.